# Ansible win_shell task seems to run bash script, but results say otherwise?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.11.0

I'm testing being able to run a bash script on a Windows host, so I wrote this simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "This is a test to run a bash script."
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  echo "The test passed!"
  cd "C:\\temp"
  touch pass.txt
else
  echo "The test failed!"
  cd "C:\\temp"
  touch fail.txt
  exit
fi
echo `hostname -f`
```

and have the following task

```
# Put this in check mode as a precaution
- name: Run the shell script
  win_shell: "c:\\temp\\test_shell.sh"
```

and see the following verbose output

```
changed: [10.227.xx.xx] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "c:\\temp\\test_shell.sh",
    "delta": "0:00:00.296871",
    "end": "2021-06-14 05:09:47.248005",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2021-06-14 05:09:46.951133",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

So it seems to have run ok. However, I don't see the `junk.txt` file being created by the `touch` line in the script. I can however login to the host, run the script there, and see the `junk.txt` file created.

Any clues?

Comment: In your output there's no data on stdout.  I'd surmise the conditional is not being evaluated as you expect it to be.  Add an echo in the else block to see if you get output in stdout.  That'd point you in a direction of what's not working as you expect.

Comment: Great idea. It does indeed execute the `else` clause since it creates the `fail.txt` file. But why?

Comment: Ok I changed the line before the `if()` clause to `touch c:\\temp\test.txt"` and get a pass scenaroio.